# Pass an argument as pattern for file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, code-coverage, command-line-arguments, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to convert a *.coverage files into XML and then use them and publish code coverage in Jenkins. However, the path to the coverage file always is different and contains Timestamp. Due to that when I call CodeCoverage.exe and I am trying to pass a pattern instead of the direct path and direct file name.

Basically everything works when I point directly to the file, but when the pattern is used, nothing is happening.

```
*This is working*
C:\CodeCoverage\CoverageTool\CodeCoverage.exe analyze -output:.\TestResults\coverage.xml ".\TestResults\coveragefiles\test.coverage

*This is not working*
C:\CodeCoverage\CoverageTool\CodeCoverage.exe analyze -output:.\TestResults\coverage.xml ".\TestResults\**\*.coverage
```

Now trying to make it working in cmd, but letter will put it to the groovy (Jenkinsfile) as a bat command.

Is it even possible in that way? Should I first find a string, make a string variable, and pass it to the codecoverage ? thanks in advance

Comment: Put in your batchfile: `for /r ".\TestResults" %%a in (*.coverage) do echo %%a`. From there it should be easy.

Comment: …or `for /D %%J in (".\TestResults\*") do for %%I in ("%%~J\*.coverage") do echo "%%~I"` in case the `.coverage` files are always at the same directory hierarchy level…

Comment: I am putting it in groovy (Jenkinsfile) like `bat "for /r ".\TestResults" %%a in (*.coverage) do echo %%a"` but without success even if I do a groovy syntax like `bat "for /r "./TestResults" %%a in (*.coverage) do echo %%a"` . Sorry for that but I am missing something ?

Comment: Don't know about Jenkins. If it takes a command line, try to replace each `%%` with a single `%`